# Entity Framework Code First column name issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am having an issue with Entity Framework code first.

There is an existing column in my SQL database called 'myId'. I am adding it to my class like so:

```
public virtual int? myId { get; set; }
```

I run: update-database -connectionStringName '[SiteName]' -force

All runs successfully but when I look in the database I see the existing column has been changed to 'myId1'. I'm not sure why the name of my existing column is being changed and not used? As you can see it has appended a '1' to the name....?

Any ideas would be gratefully received!

Comment: why update the database if the column still exists ? One of the goal of update-database is to update the database schema to put i in conformity with the model. In you case new field in the model => new field in the schema. As the name is not available a new name is created.

Comment: If I don't run the update I get the following... "The model backing the '[DBCContext]' context has changed since the database was create"

Comment: how was initially created the database ? That is, why do you have a myId column ?

Comment: The column was added by someone else (not here to ask) and does not appear in the entity. I guess the column was added manually to the database.

Comment: that is the point, is it possible to drop it ? btw: virtual on an int seems useless to me. Virtual are for related entity. And your model should have a related entity using myId as Key...

Comment: I can't drop the column and I noticed the virtual and removed.

Comment: well that means that myId is in use for another relation (for which property ?), then I suggest to use myId1 as property name to avoid future confusions.

Comment: This is not an option unfortunately. If I use [NotMapped] it doesn't use the value...

Comment: use `public int? myId1 { get; set; }`, but this is just the key... do you setup a relation on it ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume myId is not PK!?

```
`public int? myId { get; set; }`
```

and add your migration as

```
`AlterColumn("tablename", "myId", c => c.Int(nullable: true));`
```

Then run Update-database command.